# KMZ with orthomosaic shows white squares with red Xs when zooming in Google Earth Pro?

Tags: google-earth, imagery, kmz

Every time in the morning when I first open my Google Earth Pro, Why does my kmz that has an orthomosaic show white squares with red X's when you zoom in?  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I tried to clear out the caches but it is still showing it. Can anyone out there help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the KMZ being pulled over a webservice, local drive or network drive?

Comment: are you using localhost (dns) or ip 127.0.0.1 for the tiles?

Comment: No, I did not download anything. It was export from PhotoScan using Kmz.

Comment: The red X means that Earth can't load the image for that tile. That can be for a variety of reasons, so first thing to try is usually to get the URL or file path for one of the images or tiles, and see if you can open it in a browser. That could give you clues as to why Earth can't access the image.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Which browser can I open from kmz ?

Comment: I think I deleted them the tiles that I exported from PhotoScan. But when I open it it still shows the image; however, if I save the kmz in Earth and the next day I open it it will show the X like you mention.@ChristiaanAdams