# ECW to KML from ArcGIS Desktop failing to open in Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, kml, google-earth, ecw

i have some .ECW file and i want to convert to KML to used in another program (AutoCAD).. 
so i convert this file using conversion tools which is ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 provide..
but i have problem in here.. 
when i just convert directly (without set the output image setting) it was successful the KML output size file is arround 500KB but the file is became blur because low resolution in this file..
so decide to set the resolution in the layer to KML tool.. 
here is my setting.

```
image size: 100,000
DPI: 100,000
```

that file is successfully converted the file size is around 300 mb.. but when tried to open it in google earth it just show square box and X red..

How do I do it?

Comment: What precise ArcGIS tool did you use including all parameter values?  When you created your lower resolution KML did it open in Google Earth?  When you created your high resolution KML and waited for perhaps up to an hour did the red X finally get replaced by an image?

Comment: i have used this tool
conversion > to KML > layer to KML, there are an option to set your image quality output.. 
yes it is.. its open precisely in google earth.. 
i dont try to wait after i import that file in google earth.. cz i think its an error..

Comment: The square box and x red is what I asked before so here is the link to it https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289836/why-does-kmz-with-orthomosaic-show-white-squares-with-red-xs-when-zooming-in-goo

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your exported image (100,000 pixels square) is way too big for Google Earth.

Google Earth has limits on how big of an image ("texture") it can overlay on the map. These limits change per machine, since it's dependent on the capabilities of each machine's graphics card or chip. If you try to load an image that's too big (or which Earth can't access), then you'll see the red X instead.  In Google Earth Pro (desktop app), find the "About Google Earth" menu item, where it will tell you the "maximum texture size" for your machine. Most machines these days can display images from 4096 to 8192 pixels square. Some can go up to 16384 or higher... but some older machines can only display 2048 pixel images.

If your overlays are intended for public distribution, then you'll probably want to limit them to 2048 or maybe 4096 pixels square, for compatibility with most users machines. If they are only for your own use, then you can go up to whatever your max texture size is.

There are many techniques for getting larger datasets into Google Earth, but they generally get pretty complicated, as most involve tiling the data (vector or raster), and serving the tile pyramid via a tree of Regionated NetworkLinked KMLs.  There are a few tools out there for creating the raster version, often called a "SuperOverlay". If your source data is vector data, then you might also consider simplifying it and seeing if you can export it as a reasonably sized vector KML (points/lines/polygons).